# yii2 memcashe always return false

Tags: nginx, yii2, memcached

I want  use memcashe, so as not to recalculate the values every time.

```
 'cache' => [
                            'class' => 'yii\caching\MemCache',
                            'useMemcached' => true,
                            'servers' => [
                                    [
                                            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                                            'port' => 11211,
                                    ],
                            ],
                    ],
```

And try call

```
    $key = "installs" . $this->id;
        $cache = \Yii::$app->cache;
        $data = $cache->get($key);
        if(!$data){
        $cache->set($key, $data);
     }
        return $data;
```

But $data always equal false.

my nginx settings:

```
 #memcashe
        location ~ \ {
                default_type text/html;
                set $cachable 1;
                if ($request_method != GET) {
                        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80;
                        set $cachable 0;
                        break;
                }

                if ($http_cookie ~* "no_cache") {
                        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80;
                        set $cachable 0;
                        break;
                }

                set $memcached_key "{$cookie_devicetype}_{$request_uri}";
                memcached_pass 127.0.0.1:11211;
                if ($cachable = 1) {
                        add_header X-Header-Memcached true;
                }
                error_page 404 = @proxy;
        }
```

How to use memesache with yii2 correctly?

Comment: But you set the false in to the $data variable when you check if it exists in cache. What you expecting to get?

Comment: Have you tried to assign true to the $data inside the if statement?